# Concatenating dataframes read from multiple aws s3 bucket generate NoneType error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a bunch of `csv` files I need to read and group into one single dataframe. These files re in an `aws s3` bucket and a subfolder of it. Reading the files is not really an issue. The problem is that I get an error message when doing this, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
import io
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder/file_prefix")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), sep=",",encoding='utf8')        
    frame =[df,temp]
    df = pd.concat(frame)
```

So, my idea is starting with an empty `df`, to use `read_csv` only on files with a given prefix in a given bucket folder.

Now, I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

but at the same time i do get info that indicates I'm not completely far off:

```
            id       date  success      on     off  quota  errors
0         130  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
1         433  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
2         810  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
3        2889  2020-12-09     True  1653.0  1707.0  0.968     NaN
4        5410  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
..        ...         ...      ...     ...     ...    ...     ...
2         810  2021-01-12     True    50.0    47.0  1.064     NaN
3        2889  2021-01-12     True   190.0   179.0  1.061     NaN
4        5410  2021-01-12     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
5        6069  2021-01-12     True  1736.0  1779.0  0.976     NaN
6        6128  2021-01-12     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN

[232 rows x 7 columns]
```

What in my code is wrong so that it would generate that error? Any help would be appreciated.

Another alternative, if it isn't possible to answer this:

If I change the code to

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('my bucket')
import io
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder/prefix")

df = []

for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), encoding='utf8',sep=",")        
    df.append(temp)
```

How can I make

```
[          Id        date  success      on     off  quota  errors
 0        130  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
 1        433  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 2        810  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
 3       2889  2020-12-09     True  1653.0  1707.0  0.968     NaN
 4       5410  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 5       6069  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
 6       6128  2020-12-09     True  2202.0  2182.0  1.009     NaN,
           id        date  success      on     off  quota  errors
 0        130  2020-12-10     True   634.0   556.0  1.140     NaN
 1        433  2020-12-10    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 2        810  2020-12-10     True   464.0   442.0  1.050     NaN
 3       2889  2020-12-10     True   940.0   915.0  1.027     NaN
 4       5410  2020-12-10    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 5       6069  2020-12-10     True  2926.0  2879.0  1.016     NaN
 6       6128  2020-12-10     True    32.0    32.0  1.000     NaN,
           id        date  success      on     off  quota  errors
 0        130  2020-12-11     True   366.0   341.0  1.073     NaN
 1        433  2020-12-11    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 2        810  2020-12-11     True   204.0   201.0  1.015     NaN
 3       2889  2020-12-11     True   359.0   362.0  0.992     NaN
 4       5410  2020-12-11    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
 5       6069  2020-12-11     True  1601.0  1588.0  1.008     NaN
 6       6128  2020-12-11     True   703.0   705.0  0.997     NaN,
           id        date  success     on    off  quota  errors
 0        130  2020-12-12     True  162.0  153.0  1.059     NaN
 1        433  2020-12-12    False    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
 2        810  2020-12-12     True  153.0  147.0  1.041     NaN
 3       2889  2020-12-12    False    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
 4       5410  2020-12-12    False    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
 5       6069  2020-12-12     True  690.0  701.0  0.984     NaN
 6       6128  2020-12-12     True    0.0    0.0  1.000     NaN]
```

into a dataframe? I tried `DF = pd.DataFrame(df)` but it is obviously wrong.

**EDIT: Reproducible Data**

All the csv files in the bucket are of this form

```
Id,date,success,on,off,quota,errors
130,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
433,2020-12-09,False,,,,
810,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
2889,2020-12-09,True,1653.0,1707.0,0.968,
5410,2020-12-09,False,,,,
6069,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
6128,2020-12-09,True,2202.0,2182.0,1.009,
```

Here is a second example

```
Id,date,success,on,off,quota,errors
130,2020-12-11,True,366.0,341.0,1.073,
433,2020-12-11,False,,,,
810,2020-12-11,True,204.0,201.0,1.015,
2889,2020-12-11,True,359.0,362.0,0.992,
5410,2020-12-11,False,,,,
6069,2020-12-11,True,1601.0,1588.0,1.008,
6128,2020-12-11,True,703.0,705.0,0.997,
```

All the missing value a left blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below runs fine.

```
import pandas as pd

csv1 ="""Id,date,success,on,off,quota,errors
130,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
433,2020-12-09,False,,,,
810,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
2889,2020-12-09,True,1653.0,1707.0,0.968,
5410,2020-12-09,False,,,,
6069,2020-12-09,True,0.0,0.0,1.000,
6128,2020-12-09,True,2202.0,2182.0,1.009,"""

csv2="""Id,date,success,on,off,quota,errors
130,2020-12-11,True,366.0,341.0,1.073,
433,2020-12-11,False,,,,
810,2020-12-11,True,204.0,201.0,1.015,
2889,2020-12-11,True,359.0,362.0,0.992,
5410,2020-12-11,False,,,,
6069,2020-12-11,True,1601.0,1588.0,1.008,
6128,2020-12-11,True,703.0,705.0,0.997,"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv1))
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv2))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv('aws_toy.csv')
print(df, '\n')

avg_quota = df.groupby('date').agg(avg_quota=('quota', 'mean')).reset_index()
print(avg_quota, '\n')

select_quota = df.filter(['on'])
print(select_quota, '\n')
```

Ouput:

```
     Id        date  success      on     off  quota  errors
0   130  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
1   433  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
2   810  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
3  2889  2020-12-09     True  1653.0  1707.0  0.968     NaN
4  5410  2020-12-09    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
5  6069  2020-12-09     True     0.0     0.0  1.000     NaN
6  6128  2020-12-09     True  2202.0  2182.0  1.009     NaN
0   130  2020-12-11     True   366.0   341.0  1.073     NaN
1   433  2020-12-11    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
2   810  2020-12-11     True   204.0   201.0  1.015     NaN
3  2889  2020-12-11     True   359.0   362.0  0.992     NaN
4  5410  2020-12-11    False     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
5  6069  2020-12-11     True  1601.0  1588.0  1.008     NaN
6  6128  2020-12-11     True   703.0   705.0  0.997     NaN 

         date  avg_quota
0  2020-12-09     0.9954
1  2020-12-11     1.0170 

       on
0     0.0
1     NaN
2     0.0
3  1653.0
4     NaN
5     0.0
6  2202.0
0   366.0
1     NaN
2   204.0
3   359.0
4     NaN
5  1601.0
6   703.0
```

Comment: Then it works just fine and with no error. It return the df I want. But how can I work with it?

Comment: What I mean is the I cannot filter, groupby, save to csv or anything else. Anything I do (apart from ```print(pd.concat(df)) ```) results in the ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'``` error.

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to answer without having the data. Perhaps you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added two examples of how the csv-files look like.

Comment: The CSV examples you posted can be aggregated and read without issues - see the answer.